# Search multiple tables and display as multiple tables

Tags: php, sql, database, html-table

I want my users to search my database to return data from two different tables which I have done using UNION but I want it to not only search from two tables but to also display as two tables..How can I go about doing this?

```
  $result .= "<table border='1'>";
    $result .="<tr><td>Cater</td><td>Part</td><td>Gids</td></tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $result .= '<tr>';
        $result .= '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
        $result .= '<td>'.$row['Part'].'</td>';
        $result .= '<td>'.$row['Gid'].'</td>';
        $result .= '</tr>';
    }
    $result .= "</table>"; 
    $result .= "<table border='1'>";
    $result .="<tr><td>Cater</td><td>Dish</td><td>Gids</td></tr>";
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
        $result .= '<tr>';
        $result .= '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
        $result .= '<td>'.$row['Dish'].'</td>';
        $result .= '<td>'.$row['Gid'].'</td>';
        $result .= '</tr>';
    }
    $result .= "</table>";
```

Comment: Well, then just display it as two tables.

Comment: I have two tables in my php but it still only displaying as one table.

Comment: Nothing stops you from creating 2 `<table>...</table>` blocks in HTML

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do it this way, you need some way to tell where the first results end and the second start. An easy way is to add an extra column in the result set:

```
Select
    0 as resultset,
    Name,
    Part,
    Gid
From
    Parts
Union All
    1,
    Name,
    Dish,
    Gid
From
    Dishes
Order By
    resultset -- I'm not sure if you need this, or whether you get it for free
```

Then you need to break out of the first loop if you've moved to the second result set. Also, the column names in the union will all reflect the first part, so I've changed Dish to Part. You also have to deal with the possibility that either or both of the parts of the union may return nothing.

```
$result .= "<table border='1'>";
$result .="<tr><td>Cater</td><td>Part</td><td>Gids</td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql) && $row['resultset'] === 0) {
    $result .= '<tr>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Part'].'</td>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Gid'].'</td>';
    $result .= '</tr>';
}
$result .= "</table>"; 
$result .= "<table border='1'>";
$result .="<tr><td>Cater</td><td>Dish</td><td>Gids</td></tr>";
while ($row){
    $result .= '<tr>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Part'].'</td>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Gid'].'</td>';
    $result .= '</tr>';
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
}
$result .= "</table>";
```

Comment: right now i have it like this: SELECT * FROM `Cater Gids` where Cater like '%$term' UNION SELECT * FROM `Cater Food` where Cater like '%$term'

Comment: I must be writing the statement wrong as I keep on getting errors

Comment: @RobertOlson Here's an example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fcf6f/1 apparently you need to alias the tables if you use `*`.

Comment: If you are using ORDER BY, you need to surround SELECT statements with brackets. `(SELECT ...) UNION ALL (SELECT ...) ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Laurence, right now you are trying to `ORDER` second `SELECT`, not the whole result. But in the second `SELECT`statement you haven't a column named `resultset` (pre-UNION statement has it, also whole result has it, but the second statement hasn't column named `resultset`). Per [MySql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html): "To use an ORDER BY or LIMIT clause to sort or limit the entire UNION result, parenthesize the individual SELECT statements and place the ORDER BY or LIMIT after the last one"

Comment: @Laurence, I've just added another quotation from the documentation, because my first quotation was not exactly for this case, sorry.

Comment: @SergeyRonin explain http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7fcf6f/4 this is ordering over the result of the union, not the individual bits. This quote should help "A statement without parentheses is equivalent to one parenthesized as just shown."

Comment: So I tried this but its not returning my result as it was before: SELECT 0 AS resultset, c . * 
FROM  `Cater Gids` c
WHERE Cater LIKE  '%a%'
UNION SELECT 1 , f. * 
FROM  `Cater Food` f
WHERE Cater LIKE  '%a%'
ORDER BY resultset

Comment: @RobertOlson play with one of my SQLFiddle examples to make it more like what you're seeing, then when you're done, post the URL back here.

Answer (score 0):

Your probably do have two tables but right next to each other. Try putting something visble in between. I put an HR but you can put what makes sense visually for your page. Even a BR ot table header text would work.

```
$result .= "<table border='1'>";
$result .="<tr><td>Cater</td><td>Part</td><td>Gids</td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $result .= '<tr>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Part'].'</td>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Gid'].'</td>';
    $result .= '</tr>';
}
$result .= "</table>"; 

$result .= "<hr />";         <=========

$result .= "<table border='1'>";
$result .="<tr><td>Cater</td><td>Dish</td><td>Gids</td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $result .= '<tr>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Name'].'</td>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Dish'].'</td>';
    $result .= '<td>'.$row['Gid'].'</td>';
    $result .= '</tr>';
}
$result .= "</table>";
```